# LazyHighcharts scatter graph issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having an issue displaying the data in my scatter high charts graph. I'm trying to pass speed as the x axis and established a the y. If i remove the variables from the f.series and place data => [[3,120]] it works, but the variables give me a blank graph.

```
  @planter_speed = PlanterSpeed.find(params[:id])

  @data = CSV.open(@planter_speed.file.path, :headers => false,
                           :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')
  speed = []
  established = []
  @data.each do |row|  
  speed << row[0]
  established << row[1].to_i
  end

  @graph = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.chart(:height => '300')
  f.xAxis(:title => {:text => 'Speed km/hr',  
         :margin => 20, style: { color: '#333'}}, :min => 0, :max => 16)
  f.yAxis [min: 0, max: 120]
  f.series(:type => 'scatter', :name => 
         '% Established over planted', 
          data: [[speed, established]], :color => '#00463f')
  f.plotOptions({line: {enableMouseTracking: false}})
  f.legend({:align => 'center', :verticalAlign=> 'top', 
           :y => 0, :borderWidth => 0, style: {color: "#333"}})
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data needs to be an array of points like [[x1,y1], [x2,y2]]. Instead of building speed and established as separate arrays, make an array of arrays:

```
  data = []
  @data.each do |row|  
    data << [row[0].to_i, row[1].to_i]
  end
```

Then, setup the chart just as:

```
data: data
```

Comment: Great thanks Steakchaser. I also had to row[0].to_i to display speed results as well.